# PDF file as pictograms and text color

Tags: color, includegraphics

I would like to be able to use PDF files as pictograms in my document with the additional feature that the pictograms take the color of the text.

The PDF file I use is black.

So far, in order to use a PDF file as a pictogram, I use the command `\includegraphics{}` and then `\scalerel*{}` so that they have a good size.

When I change the color of the text, of course, the pictogram keeps the original color of the PDF. See for instance the picture at the end of the message.

Do you have an idea on how to do to be able to use PDF as pictograms in this way?

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65083/2388 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150219/2388.

Comment: If you can find a suitable icon in Font Awesome 5 then you can use the duotone options to color the icon (Pro version only), see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528878. There is a chalkboard teacher icon, see the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf) on page 8.

Comment: Thanks @Marijn but I have many pictograms as this one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you if there is an automatic way to remove the color info of a PDF ? Anyway, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option that could be relatively easily scripted for many PDFs.

I made a simple PDF black star in Inkscape (let's call it `star.pdf`).

I can uncompress it using `pdftk`:

```
pdftk star.pdf output star2.pdf uncompress
```

Then let's use `sed` to remove black fill and stroke setting commands (this assumes that your PDF only uses RGB black and they are in this format: `0 0 0 rg` and `0 0 0 RG`):

```
sed 's/0.0.0.[rR][gG]/        /g' < star2.pdf > star3.pdf
```

So `star3.pdf` now has its black colour commands removed.

Here's a sample test TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{star3.pdf}

\color{blue}

\includegraphics{star3.pdf}

\includegraphics{star.pdf}

\color{magenta}

\includegraphics{star3.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]